# Migrating 2012R2 RDS to 2019 RDS by in place upgrades?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, windows-server-2019

I have a working 2012R2 RDS infrastructure with following hosts: 
1 2012R2 DC 
1 2019 DC 
1 2012R2 Host as RDS Gateway, RDS Broker, RDS Webaccess 
few 2012R2 Session Hosts 
few 2019 Session Hosts 

Now I wanted to upgrade to 2019 RDS, but because I have to start with the connection broker I ask myself, can I do an in-place upgrade to 2019 from that 2012R2 host running GW, Broker and WA?

I want the 2012R2 Session Hosts stay at this version for some time, so just an upgrade of the rest.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, actually it's more you that can answer us. As did you tried with with clone to do the upgrade, and does all your software are 2019 ready ?

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same thing, in a smaller environment, for one of our customers. The machines were upgraded via in-place to Windows Server 2019 without any problems.

Just remember to activate Windows after the installation routine is done. The one thing remaining (for me) is, how to update the RD web access webseite, as it's still showing the "Windoows Server 2012 R2" version.

All the best and good luck!